# Xcode: SDWebImage clear cache for single image

Tags: xcode4, uiimageview, sdwebimage

I'm using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to asynchronous image downloader with cache support.

It's working perfectly except that sometimes the image got updated on the server with same name, thus I need to clear it from client device cache but no success!

I found [here](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/111) that I have to use "removeImageForKey" but it's not recognized by Xcode!

I'm using the following code to set the image:

```
[imgPic setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domain.com/image.jpg"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmpPic.png"]];
```

What's the correct way to call removeImageForKey? What do I have to import rather than UIImageView+WebCache.h?

Answer (score 55):

```
- (void)removeImageForKey:(NSString *)key fromDisk:(BOOL)fromDisk;
```

API is right. It work for me.
Do you know the api is in class SDImageCache which is a singleton class.
You could use it like this:

```
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] removeImageForKey:image_url fromDisk:YES];
```

Comment: It comes with a completion block now: [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] removeImageForKey: fromDisk: withCompletion:]

Answer (score 21):

```
#import "SDImageCache.h"

....

[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] removeImageForKey:@"http://domain.com/image.jpg" fromDisk:YES];
```